# Is possible to sort a jqueryui selectmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an HTML select, without any special stuff converted to jquery-ui selectmenu on this way:

```
$("#cboTitulaciones").selectmenu().selectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("overflowSelectMenu");
```

And my boss said me that jqueryui allow to sort this element, but I don't see any function to do that on documentation or Google...

Is it possible?

I think the only way is generate a sorted html select, is not?
Thanks..

Comment: yes first sort selectmenu then convert it  kindly refer http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/kCwvJ  for sorting select menu

Comment: Works perfect,thanks!